# Printer config file in *nix

Tags: linux, unix, printing, permissions, cups

**Are the settings or configuration specifics of a printer on a *nix system using CUPS stored in a file?**  My assumption is yes, as *nix systems seem to use files for everything as opposed to using a registry system as does Windows.  If so, **where are such files located?**  Are they capable of having their file **permissions modified**, and if so, what could cause such a thing to occur in a non-manual way?

This question relates to [one of my other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17727041/1961815) in helping to explore a single, individual theory toward an answer there, but is decidedly separate.

Comment: It depends. Different unix variation uses different systems for printing. (I think) the most prevalent for Linux is CUPS.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling My office does use CUPS.  Thank you, I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: Try `/etc/cups`. Also, did the perms change for the entire dir, or just for an individual file? What did the perms change to?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I do not know what, if anything changed, or even what exists. Please consider this question, which is theoretical and abstract, separate from the other question, which is trying to solve a specific problem.  Here, I am not concerned about what happened to my specific files, just about how the files work in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check on /etc/cups, for printers the file is printers.conf.

They can have permissions modified since they usually belong to the lp group, not a single user. Check cron jobs, system updates and any other cups interface that your distribution provides.